# Scikit learn: Why is my k-means clustering scatter plot so ugly?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

```
def get_nouns (text):
    tagger = MeCab.Tagger()
    words = []

    for c in tagger.parse(text).splitlines()[:-1]:
        if len(c.split('\t')) < 2:
            continue
        surface, feature = c.split('\t')
        pos = feature.split(',')[0]
        if pos == '名詞':  # noun 
            words.append(surface)
    return ' '.join(words)


def bio():
    biolist =[]
    howmany = 10
    for giin in read:
        if len(giin["education"]) < 1:
            continue
        biolist.append(get_nouns(" ".join(giin["education"])))
    ######################################################
    nparray = np.array (biolist)
    cv = CountVectorizer()
    bags = cv.fit_transform(nparray)
    tfidf=TfidfTransformer(norm='l2', sublinear_tf=True).fit_transform(bags)
    km_model = KMeans(n_clusters=howmany, init='k-means++')
    km_model.fit_transform(tfidf)
    lsa2 = TruncatedSVD(2)
    compressed_text_list = lsa2.fit_transform(tfidf)
    compressed_center_list = lsa2.fit_transform(km_model.cluster_centers_)

    X = []
    Y = []
    X_cent = []
    Y_cent = []

    for x, y in compressed_text_list:
        X.append(x)
        Y.append(y)
    for x, y in compressed_center_list:
        X_cent.append(x)
        Y_cent.append(y)

    clus_list = []
    for i in range (howmany):
        clus_list.append([])
        for a in biolist:
            if km_model.labels_[biolist.index(a)] == i:
                clus_list[i].append(a)

    for a in clus_list:
        print (a)
        print ("   ")

    plt.scatter(X, Y,  c = km_model.labels_)
    plt.scatter(X_cent, Y_cent, c="r", marker = "+")

    plt.show()
```

I have this code that clusters educational history of people into 10 groups. My scatter plot looks like this.
[image]

As you can see, the scatter plot is not really sorted into groups and different colors are mixed up with one another. How could this code be changed to make the grouping more precise?

Comment: Well, that's how the algorithm found the clusters. Visualization is just a tool to see what your algorithm found.

Comment: I see on the internet other people getting really clear cut clustering and I look at their code and can't quiet figure out what I am doing wrong. Should I just accept this as a result?

Comment: According to the code I see (`howmany = 10`) you have 10 clusters, which you're trying to display in 2 dimensions. One thing that might help is to increase the plot dimensions to 3D, you might start to see more separation

Comment: Looking at the plot I'd assume that there are more/different dimensions to your data than are shown in the plot. If you have data with two dimensiosns and you run k-means on those two dimensions then plot those two dimensions you'll get clear areas of each colour.

Comment: Yes. I basically vectororized texts into several hundred dimension vectors and compressed them into 2D. I will try displaying them in 3D. Is there any parameter I can set with k means that will improve the result?

Comment: Note k-means does not guarantee you the persistence of results. Next time you run it, you get a slihhtly different grouping.

Comment: One solution to make it better looking and to get more insights from the visualization would be to hold 1 variable constant and test at most 2 clusters at a time against that one. The question changes from "what groups do I have in my data" to "what groups do I have compared to this variable", but testing 10 against each other doesn't give as good of insights as you can see visually.

Comment: You may also want to consider if 10 is the optimal value of K. One of the ways is using [elbow method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ml-determine-the-optimal-value-of-k-in-k-means-clustering)